# ImageMagick multiple operations in single invocation - round corner

Tags: imagemagick, mask

ImageMagick multiple operations in single invocation

Hello. I am not good at English.
I'd appreciate it if you understand.

I created a Mask Image.

convert -size 600x735 xc:none -draw "roundrectangle 0,0,600,735,45,45" mask.png

Create rounded edges for multiple files.

I'd like to make a single combined(joined) file.

convert in.png -matte mask.png -compose DstIn -composite after1.png

convert in2.png -matte mask.png -compose DstIn -composite after2.png

convert in3.png -matte mask.png -compose DstIn -composite after3.png

convert after1.png after2.png after3.png -append result.png

Can I do the above process at once?
I'd like to cut it down with one or two lines of command.

Comment: SO is for programming questions, but this question is about how to achieve something without any programming at all. )You already know how to do it with a four-line shell script.) I think it'll fit better on another site.

Answer (score 2):

If you already created the mask, you may be able to simplify the rest of it into one command like this...

```
convert in.png in2.png in3.png null: ^
  -matte mask.png -compose dstin -layers composite +append result.png
```

That would read in the three input images and do the mask composite on each of them all at the same time. Then it appends the three results into a single file for the output.

Comment: Wow, Great~! Wonderful~! Excellent~! I am very happy. Thank you so much~~~~~~~~~~!!!!!!!

Answer (score 1):

This will do what you ask in Imagemagick using [parenthesis processing](https://imagemagick.org/Usage/basics/#parenthesis)

Unix syntax:

```
convert \
\( in.png -matte mask.png -compose DstIn -composite \) \
\( in2.png -matte mask.png -compose DstIn -composite \) \
\( in1.png -matte mask.png -compose DstIn -composite \) \
-append result.png
```

Windows syntax:

```
convert ^
( in.png -matte mask.png -compose DstIn -composite ) ^
( in2.png -matte mask.png -compose DstIn -composite ) ^
( in1.png -matte mask.png -compose DstIn -composite ) ^
-append result.png
```

I note that you have in1.png in the third convert. Did you mean in3.png?

Please always identify your Imagemagick version and platform/OS, since syntax differs.

Comment: Wow, Thanks a lot of you.
My OS: Windows 10
ImageMagick-7.0.8-68-portable-Q16-x64

Answer (score 1):

This may be of interest for those wanting to make rounded corners with Imagemagick. Unix syntax.

Input:

[image]

**Imagemagick 6**

Rounded Corners:

```
convert thumbnail.gif \( +clone -alpha extract \
\( -size 15x15 xc:black -draw 'fill white circle 15,15 15,0' -write mpr:arc +delete \) \
\( mpr:arc \) -gravity northwest -composite \
\( mpr:arc -flip \) -gravity southwest -composite \
\( mpr:arc -flop \) -gravity northeast -composite \
\( mpr:arc -rotate 180 \) -gravity southeast -composite \) \
-alpha off -compose CopyOpacity -composite thumbnail_rounded.png
```

[image]

Rounded Corners With Shadow:

```
convert thumbnail.gif \( +clone -alpha extract \
\( -size 15x15 xc:black -draw 'fill white circle 15,15 15,0' -write mpr:arc +delete \) \
\( mpr:arc \) -gravity northwest -composite \
\( mpr:arc -flip \) -gravity southwest -composite \
\( mpr:arc -flop \) -gravity northeast -composite \
\( mpr:arc -rotate 180 \) -gravity southeast -composite \) \
-alpha off -compose CopyOpacity -composite -compose over \
\( +clone -background black -shadow 80x3+5+5 \) \
+swap -background none -layers merge thumbnail_rounded_shadow.png
```

[image]

**Imagemagick 7**

Rounded Corners:

```
magick thumbnail.gif \
\( +clone -fill black -colorize 100 -fill white -draw 'roundrectangle 0,0 %w,%h 15,15' \) \
-alpha off -compose CopyOpacity -composite thumbnail_rounded2.png
```

[image]

Rounded Corners With Shadow:

```
magick thumbnail.gif \
\( +clone -fill black -colorize 100 -fill white -draw 'roundrectangle 0,0 %w,%h 15,15' \) \
-alpha off -compose CopyOpacity -composite -compose over \
\( +clone -background black -shadow 80x3+5+5 \) \
+swap -background none -layers merge thumbnail_rounded_shadow2.png
```

[image]

Comment: Oh~~! It's great~!!!!!!!!!!!! Thank you very much for this rich knowledge.